# make: execvp: g++: Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-4, centos

I'm trying to install `therubyracer` on Amazon Linux AMI (~centOS).

```
[www@ip-10-0-0-125 root]$ gem install therubyracer
Fetching: libv8-3.16.14.3-x86_64-linux.gem (100%)
Successfully installed libv8-3.16.14.3-x86_64-linux
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/www/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling handles.cc
make: execvp: g++: Permission denied
make: *** [handles.o] Error 127

Permission denied @ dir_chdir - /root

Gem files will remain installed in /home/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/therubyracer-0.12.1/gem_make.out
[www@ip-10-0-0-125 root]$
```

I am not sure what to try.. I'm installing it manually on the server with `gem install therubyracer`. I have tried doing libv8 first, many different versions and combinations of versions.

I'm running this under the `www` user in the `~` directory.

Thanks

Comment: At a first glance it means you don't have permissions to run the `g++` program (which is odd).  If you run `g++ --version` from your shell prompt what do you get?  If you run `ls -l $(type g++)` what do you get?

Comment: http://pastie.org/8906232

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You haven't installed `g++` (the GNU C++ compiler) on your system... that makes it hard to compile things :-).

I don't have a copy of centos handy, but something like `sudo yum install g++` will probably get you a compiler.

Comment: `yum install gcc-c++` I think